# Is there any usage of the verb ‘want’ in causative form?

Tags: causative-verbs

I know that the verbs such as *let*, *make*, and *have* are causative, and when looking on the internet I found out that people generally don’t treat the verb *want* as causative.

However, if we look at these two examples with *want*:

1. People are wanting their favorite words added.
2. They want their issue done.

Then to me that usage reminds me of the causative form just like in these next two examples:

3. I had to have my TV repaired three times in the first year.
4. She made them cry for no reason.

Comment: The verbs *let*, *make* and *have* are not causative; when they are used in combinations with other verbs, they turn them causative. One of those verbs is *want*. Why can't I want that? Let me want it. Make me want it. Would you really have me want such a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at it wrong. It isn't individual verbs that are causative, usually; it's the constructions they're in, which may or may not require them.

For instance, there's a causative construction with *have*

- *He had his tires rotated.*

meaning, in this case, that he caused someone else to rotate the tires on his car. That doesn't mean *have* is a causative verb; it's not. It just means the causative construction uses *have*.

The example sentences you gave (leaving off the irrelevant bells and whistles)

- *People want their favorite words added*.
- *They want their issue done*.

are both examples of the syntactic rule called [*to be*-deletion](https://www.ingentaconnect.com/contentone/cls/pcls/1973/00000009/00000001/art00005?crawler=true&mimetype=application/pdf). Note that *to be* may be added in each case, making a passive infinitive complement:

- *People want their favorite words **to be** added*.
- *They want their issue **to be** done*.

So that's what happened to those sentences. *Want* does not **cause** things, though it can motivate people to do things. But that's not causation.

The other two examples you mention are real causative constructions,
one with *have* that I mentioned above, and one with *make*, a true causative verb.

Answer (score 1):

Causative verbs are active verbs, that is verbs that tells that an action is being done. However, "want" is not an active verb as it merely indicates a state of mind; it is a stative verb. Therefore, it can't be a causative verb.

The impression of a causative relationship is wrong. You can see that if you compare the sentence "They wanted the vacationers to go to the hills." with a sentence entirely equivalent in meaning.

- They wanted that the vacationers went to the hills. (*They might have gone to the hills, then again they might not have.*)

A mere intention has been expressed; no idea that someone or something could be credited with an action can be extracted from these words.