# verb + object +(to be) p.p?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, infinitives, past-participles, complements

Can all verbs with to infinitives in the place of the object complement use both the past participle and to be p.p. form when the relationship between the object and the object complement is passive?

I expected my car **(to be) repaired** soon.

Is it okay to use either form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any usage of the verb ‘want’ in causative form?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/589201/is-there-any-usage-of-the-verb-want-in-causative-form) J Lawler's answer cites Borkin, whose paper contains 'Since it is difficult to see why verbs like _declare, consider, feel_ and _expect_ should govern [permit]  to-be–deletion, while verbs Iike _state, know, hear_ and _intend_ do not ...'. So 'I expected my car [to be] repaired soon' but not 'I intended my car repaired soon'.